# simple sum in structure with pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct

recently i started writing apps with c language. i have a problem with sum operator in below code. when i start program and i give for ex. 4 to int a; and 6 to int b; and then i want a+b witch give me 22. here is code, first i define my structure:

```
struct student {
   int a;
   int *b;
}*s1;
```

then i scan the values and the other steps:

```
int sum, x, y;
s1 = malloc(sizeof(struct student));

scanf("%d", &x);
scanf("%d", &y);

s1->a = x;
s1->b = y;
sum = (s1->a) + (s1->b);
printf("SUM: %d", sum);
```

Also i test *(s1->a) and still have problem. Thanks.

> > > > IMPORTANT: i don't want the other ways that i can solve this problem or suggesting the better ways of coding this algorithm, i just want to know why this piece of code not working properly and how can i fix it. Actually i want keep the 'b' as a pointer!

Comment: int *b;  <-- that's a pointer to int, not an int ...

Comment: @MitchWheat so how can i malloc b?

Comment: erm, using malloc!!!

Comment: i am new to c, s1->b = malloc(sizeof(struct student))?? not working

Comment: you need to read some basic tutorials....

Comment: If you inted b to be int you have a typo in the decleration, it should be int b, if you intend it to be pointer to int do read more manual regarding pointers

Comment: all of my code is okay, even when i call s1->b or s1->a but when i try to sum them i ran to problem. please notice..

Comment: "all of my code is okay" - it's far from OK!

Comment: @MitchWheat actually your Sense of humor if far from OK! :)

Comment: I wasn't joking. The mistake you have made indicates you need to read up on pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int *b` in your structure is a pointer not an `int`. To fix your code,you can assign the address of `y` to the pointer like this:

```
s1->a = x;
s1->b = &y;
sum = (s1->a) + *(s1->b); //asterisk dereferences the pointer and gets the value stored in the memory address
printf("SUM: %d", sum);
```

Or just declare `b` as an `int` variable.

Comment: (s1->*b) is it TRUE?? my compiler not allow me such this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mitch Wheat mentioned in the comments,

```
struct student {
   int a;
   int *b; // <-- this is a pointer, not an int
}*s1;
```

This has the effect that in the expression

```
(s1->a) + (s1->b);
```

pointer arithmetic is used, and the expression has the same value as `&s1->b[s1->a]` would have if `s1->b` were a valid pointer (that it isn't is a problem that is not triggered in the code).

Since `s1->a == 4` and `s1->b == memory address 6`, the numerical value of `(s1->a) + (s1->b)` then is `6 + sizeof(int) * 4`. If `sizeof(int) == 4`, this becomes `22`, and that is the behavior you get.

The solution is to make `b` an int:

```
struct student {
   int a;
   int b;
}*s1;
```

Note that this is just a description of the behavior you get, not of behavior you are guaranteed to get. On a platform where pointers have a different size from `int`s, for example, the `printf` will not work as expected because the `%d` format specified does not use the whole pointer value.

Comment: thanks for you explanation and answer. that was complete but i find my answer in above. s1->b = &y;
 sum = (s1->a) + *(s1->b);

Comment: Yes, that also works if you want to keep the pointer. Keep in mind that changing `y` then changes `*s1->b` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the definition of the structure and/or how you are using it:

```
struct student {
   int a;
   int *b;
}*s1;
```

Here `a` is an `int` but `b` is a pointer to an `int`. If `x` had that struct type, you'd need to use `x.a` but `*(x.b)` to refer to the integer. So if `s` is a pointer to the struct, you need to use `s->a` but `*(s->b)`.

However, you are using `s1` as a pointer to the struct, but trying to use `s->a` and `s->b` seemingly both as integers. That won't work because of the way you have declared the struct.

More precisely:

```
s1->a = x;
s1->b = y;
sum = (s1->a) + (s1->b);
printf("SUM: %d", sum);
```

That sum line is doing [pointer arithmetic](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) (as `s1->b` is a pointer). This is unlikely to be what you required. Remove the `*` from the definition, i.e. use:

```
struct student {
   int a;
   int b;
} *s1;
```

You don't need to change the way you `malloc()` the struct. The fact that `s1` is a pointer to the struct is a separate issue from whether the struct *contains* a pointer.